# How to get $E[\int_{t}^T2B_sdB_s|\mathcal{F}_t]=0?$

Tags: probability-theory, analysis, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation

I am computing the following Ito integral
$$
E[\int_{0}^T2B_sdB_s|\mathcal{F}_t]=E[\int_{0}^t2B_sdB_s+\int_{t}^T2B_sdB_s|\mathcal{F}_t]
$$
$$
=E[\int_{0}^t2B_sdB_s|\mathcal{F}_t]+E[\int_{t}^T2B_sdB_s|\mathcal{F}_t]
$$
the first term $\int_{0}^t2B_sdB_s$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_t$, then $E[\int_{0}^t2B_sdB_s|\mathcal{F}_t]=\int_{0}^t2B_sdB_s$.

But how to get
$$
E[\int_{t}^T2B_sdB_s|\mathcal{F}_t]=0?
$$

Comment: Use that $\int_0^T2B_s\,dB_s$ is a martingale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Ito on $B_t^2$, and you find out that $d(B_t^2)=2B_tdB_t+dt\implies \int_{[t,T]} 2B_sdB_s=B_T^2-B_t^2-(T-t)$. By using the fact that $E[B_T^2-B_t^2|\mathscr{F}_t]=(T-t)$, the claim follows.